# Prevent phoenix.js from messing with DOM

Tags: phoenix-framework, elm

I have a front end written in Elm, and it is communicating with a Phoenix back end through channels. However, it seems phoenix.js is doing something to the DOM. If the page is idle for a while, I get DOM-related errors in the console, for example:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
```

or

```
elm_db.js:3699 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

How can I prevent phoenix.js from messing with the DOM?

Edit: Here are two screenshots from the console:

[image]

[image]

client_ledger.js and client_db.js are my client files that receive and send json objects over the Phoenix channels. elm_ledger.js and elm_db.js are my compiled Elm front ends.

Comment: In your app, are you loading `phoenix_html.js`? I'd think that would be the culprit rather than `phoenix.js`.

Comment: No I'm not. I don't know what that file is.

Comment: I think you need to look at what code phoenix is loading and running. You;ve diagnosed what's causing elm to struggle but need to share code from the phoenix side